# Javascript - Return from Catch

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins

I'm learning JS and attempting to call an external function and learning about try/catch.

I've got a function that makes a new worksheet, it currently has no logic to see if a worksheet exists. I wanted to make it so if it catches an error, it assumes that it was because the worksheet existed and returns the worksheet it attempted to make (same name).

But, currently my main function goes straight to its own catch/error block if the 2nd function errors.

Is there a way for me to catch and error in the 2nd function, but return a sane value and have the main/calling function continue on?

See below, these are for an Office Add-In customizing Home.js or Taskpane.js. I basically just hit the run button 2x, the second time, I click a new cell somewhere and it should just fail on the worksheet create function, then select the range on the active sheet with the desired name.

I think perhaps its because this is all nested in a function for the entire js page, but I'm new and unsure if this is even possible.

```
'use strict';

(function () {

    Office.onReady(function () {
        // Office is ready
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // The document is ready
            $('#set-color').click(setColor);
        });
    });

    /*
     * //No Syntax Error, but failed
    function CreateWSDelIfExists(context, wsstr) {
            Excel.run(function (context) {
                //Start Func
                var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
                sheets.add(wsstr);
                return context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wsstr);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
                if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
            });
        }
    */


    function CreateWSDelIfExists(context, wsstr) {
        try {
            //Start Func
            var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
            console.log("About 2 Add WS");
            sheets.add(wsstr);
            //return context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wsstr);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            console.log("In Try Error");
            //return context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wsstr);
            console.log("In Try After Return");
        } finally {
            return context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wsstr);
        }
        console.log("Out of Try");
        
    }

    /*
    //Works fine, but catch makes calling func fail!
    function CreateWSDelIfExists(context, wsstr) {
        try {
            //Start Func
            var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
            sheets.add(wsstr);
            return context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wsstr);
        } catch (error) {
            //console.error(error);
            return context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wsstr);
        }
    }
    */
    /*
     * Functioned the same as the above try/catch version in testing
    function CreateWSDelIfExists(context, wsstr) {
        var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
        sheets.add(wsstr);
        return context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wsstr);
    }
    */

    function setColor() {
        Excel.run(function (context) {
            //Start Func
            var wsstr = "SheetName";
            var ws = CreateWSDelIfExists(context, wsstr);
            ws.activate();
            var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            var range = ws.getRange("A1:D4");
            range.values = "Hello World!";
            var lrow = ws.getUsedRange().getLastRow();
            lrow.load("rowindex");
            // Run the queued-up command, and return a promise to indicate task completion
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    //var range = ws.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, 4, 5); //This Works
                    var range = ws.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, lrow.rowIndex, 5); //This does nothing, but no errors either, just nothing.
                    range.select();
                })

            //End Func
            return context.sync();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
    }


})();
```

Example of what I'd do in VBA: (untested)

```
Sub Test()

dim ws as worksheet, wsstr as string
wsstr = "test"
Set ws = CreateWS(wsstr)
ws.activate

end sub
```

---

```
Function CreateWS(WSStr AS String) As worksheet
 On error goto ErrorHandler:
 Sheets.Add.Name = wsstr
 ErrorHandler:
 Set CreateWS = Worksheets(WSStr)
exit function
```

Comment: youre returning in the `finally` block which runs after either the try and catch block. They both have returns in them...

Comment: is `setColor` the second func you're talking about?

Comment: you have two return statements in that func, the second return will never run. However, in that first return you are returning a function. If it throws there, it will be cause in the next catch block, which is in the first function.

Comment: in the first return in `setColor` you are returning a function. If the error is being thrown in that function, it will be caught in the catch block of whatever function you called the `setColor` function in

Comment: @about14sheep to be clear, as terminology is important! when you say `first return` you mean my request for a promise/calling `CreateWS` function correct? Is there no way to isolate the catch inside the `sub function`? I could obviously look at nesting catch inside the main `setColor`, but I'd prefer to have default `catch` inside `CreateWS` that relates to that function so I can re-use it. Make sense?